# Unable to bind FromScriptableObjectResource inside subcontainer

Tags: zenject

Everything works fine if im trying to bind with FromScriptableObjectResource from parrent container but when I put this bind statement in subcontainer entities in the same subcontainer cant get the object. Cant understand why.

This works fine ModuleCameraGame is able to get ModuleCameraGameConfig:

```
public class CameraServiceInstaller : Installer<CameraServiceInstaller>
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container
            .Bind<ServiceCamera>()
            .FromSubContainerResolve()
            .ByInstaller<CameraServiceSubContainerInstaller>()
            .AsSingle();

        Container
            .Bind<ModuleCameraGameConfig>().FromScriptableObjectResource("Configs/ModuleCameraGameConfig").AsSingle();
    }
}

internal class CameraServiceSubContainerInstaller : Installer<CameraServiceSubContainerInstaller>
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container
            .Bind<ServiceCamera>()
            .AsSingle();
        Container
            .Bind<ModuleCameraGame>().FromComponentInHierarchy().AsSingle();
    }
}
```

This doesnt works cause ModuleCameraGame cant get config:

```
public class CameraServiceInstaller : Installer<CameraServiceInstaller>
 {
     public override void InstallBindings()
     {
         Container
             .Bind<ServiceCamera>()
             .FromSubContainerResolve()
             .ByInstaller<CameraServiceSubContainerInstaller>()
             .AsSingle();
     }
 }

 internal class CameraServiceSubContainerInstaller : Installer<CameraServiceSubContainerInstaller>
 {
     public override void InstallBindings()
     {
         Container
             .Bind<ServiceCamera>()
             .AsSingle();
         Container
             .Bind<ModuleCameraGame>().FromComponentInHierarchy().AsSingle();

         Container
            .Bind<ModuleCameraGameConfig>().FromScriptableObjectResource("Configs/ModuleCameraGameConfig").AsSingle();
     }
 }
```